# Array value not displaying in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, arrays, label, ios-simulator

I am making a simple calculator application that displays the equation that the user has inputed and also the output of the equation. At the top of my header file I created three integers and an array...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int Method;
int SelectNumber;
float RunningTotal;

NSMutableArray *Equation;

@interface SecondCalculatorViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UILabel *EquationLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *ResultLabel;

}

- (IBAction)OneButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)TwoButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ThreeButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)FourButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)FiveButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)SixButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)SevenButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)EightButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)NineButton:(id)sender; 
- (IBAction)ZeroButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)Plusbutton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)MinusButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)MultiplyButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DivideButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)CalculateButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ClearButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

In my implementation, I prepare each input to be displayed in a label and then also I try to save SelectNumber into the first index in the array I created. I then try to display it in the label. Here is an example of one of the buttons...

```
- (IBAction)OneButton:(id)sender {

//[Equation addObject:0];

SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
//EquationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",SelectNumber];
[Equation replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",SelectNumber]];
EquationLabel.text = [Equation objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

When I run this in the simulator and push any number, it does not display the first value in the array "Equation".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `Equation` is initialized? i.e. it is not `nil`?

Comment: @Avt it can't be initialized in the header correct? Do I do that in the .m?

Comment: yes, you should do it in the *.m file. I have added the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Equation is not initialized. You need to initialize it:

```
Equation = [NSMutableArray new];
// or Equation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`viewDidLoad` method could be a good place for this code in your case.

Comment: I added that in the viewDidLoad but I am now getting the array index out of bounds error. I am wondering if it is because I used replaceObjectAtIndex: instead of addObject: . But I tried [Equation addObject:[Equation SelectNumber]] and it didn't work either

Comment: If your array is empty you will receive exception (from docs :"index value must not exceed the bounds of the array."). Try `[Equation addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",SelectNumber]];`